# How to use JavaScript to modify the content of a Discord input box?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a Chrome browser extension based on Discord.

I used this piece of code, but still couldn't modify the content of the input box.

```js
const inputBoxElem = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]')[1]

function replaceValue(selector, value) {
  const el = selector;
  if (el) {
    el.focus();
    document.execCommand('selectAll');
    if (!document.execCommand('insertText', false, value)) {
      el.value = 'new text';
    }
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));
  }
  return el;
}

replaceValue(inputBoxElem, "Hello")
```

I want to modify the input box content by selecting all text and pasting new content, but still cannot make the modification.

```js
(async () => {
    let node = document.activeElement;

    if (!node) {
        return;
    }

    while (node.shadowRoot) {
        node = node.shadowRoot.activeElement;
    }

    const initText = getNodeText(node);

    if (!isEditAbleNode(node)) {
        return;
    }


    let text = "hello, change input box content";

    try {

        if (isInputNode(node)) {
            node.value = text;
            node.dispatchEvent(
                new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
            );
            return;
        }

        selectContent(node);
        await sleep(200);

        pasteContentEvent(node, text);
        await sleep(200);

        if (getNodeText(node).startsWith(initText)) {
            pasteContentCommand(node, text);
            await sleep(100);
        } else {
            collapseToEnd(node);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err.message);
    } finally {
    }
})();


function isInputNode(node) {
    return node.nodeName === "INPUT" || node.nodeName === "TEXTAREA";
}

function isEditAbleNode(node) {
    return node.hasAttribute("contenteditable");
}

function selectContent(node) {
    node.focus();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}

function pasteContentEvent(node, text) {
    node.focus();
    const data = new DataTransfer();
    data.setData("text/plain", text);

    const event = new ClipboardEvent("paste", { clipboardData: data });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
    data.clearData();
}

function pasteContentCommand(node, text) {
    node.focus();
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
}

function collapseToEnd(node) {
    node.focus();
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.collapseToEnd();
}

function getNodeText(node) {
    if (isInputNode(node)) {
        return node.value;
    }
    return node.innerText || node.textContent || "";
}

function sleep(delay) {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
};
```

[image]

When you continue typing, you will notice that the previously replaced content has been cleared. I've spent a day on it, and still can't solve this problem. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks.